# Android app automaticly updated from a blog

Tags: android

I have a very beginner question, I have a blog and I want to develop an android app for it. Each time I write a new post on the blog, it'll be automatically added to the app, I want the best way to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Does your blog have an RSS feed?

Comment: yes , it s a blogspot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [SAXParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) to parse the RSS feed. There's a simple example [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/04/simple-rss-reader-using-androids.html).